# Как в Qt Designer в строке QLineedit вывести ввод в переменную при нажатии QPushButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qlineedit

Код файла main.py:

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFormLayout
import design  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.QtLineEdit.text
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

отрывки двух кода строк, которые нужно считать:

```
self.hours = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.hours.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.hours.setFont(font)
        self.hours.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(205, 214, 219, 0.3);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.hours.setText("")
        self.hours.setObjectName("hours")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 341, 51))
```

```
    self.minutes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
            self.minutes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 81, 41))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
            font.setPointSize(16)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.minutes.setFont(font)
            self.minutes.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(205, 214, 219, 0.3);\n"
    "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
            self.minutes.setText("")
            self.minutes.setObjectName("minutes")
```

Comment: пожалуйста опубликуйте весь модуль `design.py`

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/hjutkqg46t89pai/design.py/file design.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, которые надо добавить

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from design import Ui_MainWindow                                         # !!!


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.QtLineEdit.text

        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)                       # +++ 

    def onClicked(self):                                                      # +++
        hours = self.hours.text()                                             # +++
        minutes = self.minutes.text()                                         # +++
        print(f'hours = {hours}, minutes = {minutes}')                        # +++ 
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ExampleApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(512, 315)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferDefault)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(True)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        MainWindow.setStatusTip("")
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.hours = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.hours.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.hours.setFont(font)
        self.hours.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(205, 214, 219, 0.3);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.hours.setText("")
        self.hours.setObjectName("hours")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 341, 51))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.textBrowser.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Yu Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textBrowser.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.textBrowser.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.textBrowser.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.minutes = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.minutes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Black")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.minutes.setFont(font)
        self.minutes.setStyleSheet("background: rgba(205, 214, 219, 0.3);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
        self.minutes.setText("")
        self.minutes.setObjectName("minutes")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 91, 41))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.textBrowser_3.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.textBrowser_3.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textBrowser_3.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.textBrowser_3.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.textBrowser_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textBrowser_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.textBrowser_3.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.textBrowser_4 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 190, 81, 41))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
        self.textBrowser_4.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setKerning(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.textBrowser_4.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser_4.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textBrowser_4.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.textBrowser_4.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.textBrowser_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.textBrowser_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.textBrowser_4.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textBrowser_4.setObjectName("textBrowser_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 170, 161, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 30);")
        self.pushButton.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.pushButton.setDefault(False)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 512, 21))
        self.menuBar.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menuLanguage = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        
# ?        self.menuLanguage.setStyleSheet("font-color: black;")
        
        self.menuLanguage.setObjectName("menuLanguage")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.actionEnglish = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionEnglish.setObjectName("actionEnglish")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.menuLanguage.addSeparator()
        self.menuLanguage.addAction(self.actionEnglish)
        self.menuLanguage.addSeparator()
        self.menuLanguage.addAction(self.action_5)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuLanguage.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Yu Gothic\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Выключить  через:</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI Light\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Часов</p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_4.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Segoe UI Light\'; font-size:16pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Минут</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выключить"))
        self.menuLanguage.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Language"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "а"))
        self.actionEnglish.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "English"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Русский"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @pecenka пожалуйста

Comment: from q1279652_ui import Ui_MainWindow Я не могу найти этот модуль:q1279652_u

Comment: @pecenka это ваш `design.py` -  `from design import Ui_MainWindow`

Comment: @pecenka я обновил свой ответ и обновил импорт

Comment: спасибо, я все исправил в программе